# User with multiple roles and multiple teams database design

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am unable to get my head around this

I want to allow users to have multiple roles and multiple teams and maybe in the future add something else.

What is the most optimal way to design this?

```
Users
---------- 
user_id
first name
last name

roles
--------
role_id
user_id (fk)
role_name

teams
-----
team_id
user_id (fk)
team name

something_else
------
selse_id
user_id (fk)
selse_name
```

and then group everything in one table like this?

```
user_profile
---------------------
user_id - username - role_name - team_name - selse_name
```

I don't know if this should be fine or not, because I am thinking it might get complicated when I pass the data to a form on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema design is similar to how I would do this.  Where your question falls apart is in the last bit about grouping everything together.

The schema should be:

```
create table users (
  user_id serial primary key,
  first_name text not null,
  last_name text not null,
  -- other columns here
);

create table roles (
  role_id serial primary key,
  role_name text not null unique,
  -- other columns here
);

create table user_role (
  id serial primary key,
  user_id int not null references users(user_id),
  role_id int not null references roles(role_id),
  unique(user_id, role_id)
);
```

Make the lookup and join tables for `teams` and `something_else` similarly.

The tricky part is pulling this data for use in a UI.  You will need to aggregate the properties or else you will have multiple rows for each user.  For example, if a `user` has three `roles`, belongs to two `teams`, and has four `something_else` rows, then joining will net you twenty-four rows for that `user`.

Assuming your UI will be web or some modern toolkit, the best way to retrieve this data would be as json.  PostgreSQL can build that json for you:

```
with aggs as (
  select u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, 
         jsonb_agg(DISTINCT to_jsonb(r)) as roles,
         jsonb_agg(DISTINCT to_jsonb(t)) as teams,
         jsonb_agg(DISTINCT to_jsonb(s)) as something_else
    from users u
         left join user_role ur on ur.user_id = u.user_id
         left join roles r on r.role_id = ur.role_id
         left join user_team ut on ut.user_id = u.user_id
         left join teams t on t.team_id = ut.team_id
         left join user_something_else us on us.user_id = u.user_id
         left join something_else s on s.something_else_id = us.something_else_id
   group by u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name
)
select to_jsonb(aggs)
  from aggs
 where user_id = ?
;
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that I can build json with postgres.
I actually went with making the roles as columns e.g(user_id, Admin, Moderator, Member). do you think this is better?

Comment: @MG91  If you are confident that you will not be adding new roles in the future, then static columns are better.  The join table approach in my answer gives you flexibility.  It is for you to decide whether that flexibility will ever be needed.  Try a web search for "YAGNI" :-)

Comment: Thanks @Mike Organek, learned a lot from you, with "YANGI" on top :-)

Comment: Sorry Mike, last question I promise. The query above is returning duplicates for roles, teams.. etc. I tried yo add distinct on user_id at the start but that's not fixing the duplicate values.

Comment: I added  DISTINCT: jsonb_agg(DISTINCT to_jsonb(r)) as roles, and I think it works. I will test it further and see :-)

Comment: @MG91  Sorry--I was away from my desk.  Yes.  That was a bad mistake on my part to leave `DISTINCT` out since the query still does the cartesian product.